# How to write a protocol document

Tags: protocols

I am writing a protocol for my Game, and I am not sure what software to use for that.

I been trying writing it in Microsoft Word, and Excel, but it's not always easy to read or edit it.

Is there any good practices or tools that can help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard tool for describing protocols is [message sequence chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_sequence_chart) which has been used by the telecom industry (and others) for decades.

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/MSC_CallOperation.png]

It is a really powerful tool you most certainly should learn and use. I recommend using http://sourceforge.net/projects/msc-generator/ to edit and generate charts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) for this. You either can implement the doc of your protocol somewhere in your source or create a stand-alone-file. Doxygen is used for source-documentation normaly but should also work well for this.

Doxygen also implements [mscgen](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/), which should become handy for your purpose.